# How can I go to the next iteration of a for loop if none of the elseif criteria are met?

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked through about a dozen answers to similar questions, and I can't believe I haven't seen this, but I don't find it anywhere. I just want my Else to send me to the next sheet if the sheet name doesn't match any of those listed. Alternatively, I want it to simply skip sheets 6 and 7.

```
    For sheetNumber = 4 To 10
    Sheets(sheetNumber).Activate
    sheetName = Sheets(sheetNumber).Name
    
        If sheetName = "Administration" Then
            dept = 100
        ElseIf sheetName = "spin4" Then
            dept = 315
        ElseIf sheetName = "Take Steps" Then
            dept = 400
        ElseIf sheetName = "Special Events" Then
            dept = 500
        ElseIf sheetName = "Major Gifts & Other Fund Rev" Then
            dept = 700
        ElseIf dept = 0 Then
    Next sheetNumber
    End If
```

I expected this to loop to the next worksheet when none of the sheet name criteria were matched. Instead it gave me a Next without For error.

Comment: Your `End If` needs to be in the loop.

Comment: Put the `End if` inside the loop

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same thing when I indent it into the loop.

Comment: Anyhow I think it is better to use a SELECT CASE statement here.

Comment: You have overlapped two scopes which is not allowed in VBA.  The  If ... end if must be wholly within the for next structure.  As an aside your if statement is acting as a lookup structure.  You could replace the if statement by using a scripting.dictionary which is expressly designed for lookup activities.  Your whole if statement would then collapse to something akin to  ' dept = departments.Item(sheetname)' where departments is a dictionary you'd have defined earlier in your code.

Comment: Thanks all for the helpful comments. I placed the next outside the loop, and accomplished the pass to the next simply by adding an Else with nothing at the end.